# 'each' highlighted by Kate in endforeach

Tags: php, kate

Earlier versions of lampp had endforeach in grey in Kate; with the latest xampp version (7.3.8) 'each' is red and underlined. This is using the colon version of foreach. Has foreach/endforeach changed or is my coding faulty somewhere?

I am a keen amateur. Substituting curly brackets for ':' and endforeach works OK. I am just curious as to why Kate is doing this.

```
<select name="startrats[]"><?php
  foreach ($startrats as $startrat): ?>
    <option value="<?php htmlout($startrat); ?>"<?php
      if ($startrat == $chunks[$i][3] echo 'selected="selected"';
      ?>><?php htmlout($startrat); ?>
    </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

No error messages. Works OK, but why the quirk in Kate?

Comment: Does it do this if you just write a simple `foreach` loop without going in and out of `<?php` mode in the body so much? That might be confusing the parser. Either way, it just sounds like a bug in Kate, and you should report it.

Comment: I placed a /* ... */ between the colon and endforeach with no change; still 'each' underlined and in red.

Comment: As I said, you should report this to the Kate developers.